# PyQT5 как добавить возможность изменения размеров виджетов

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qmainwindow

У меня есть простой интерфейс на PyQt5, который состоит из верхней и нижней зоны, разделенных горизонтальной чертой. Как я могу дать пользователю возможность перемещать эту разделительную полосу вверх и вниз, изменяя, соответственно, размеры верхней и нижней части?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1300, 700)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)
        #  верхняя часть
        self.layout_top = QHBoxLayout()
        self.list = QListView()
        self.top_table = QTableWidget()
        self.top_table.setRowCount(20)
        self.layout_top.addWidget(self.list)
        self.layout_top.addWidget(self.top_table)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_top)
        #  нижняя часть
        self.layout_bottom = QVBoxLayout()
        self.bot_table = QTableWidget()
        self.bot_table.setRowCount(20)
        self.layout_bottom.addWidget(self.bot_table)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_bottom)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `Splitter`:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1300, 700)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)
        #  верхняя часть
        self.frame_top = QFrame()
        self.layout_top = QHBoxLayout()
        self.list = QListView()
        self.top_table = QTableWidget()
        self.top_table.setRowCount(20)
        self.layout_top.addWidget(self.list)
        self.layout_top.addWidget(self.top_table)
        self.frame_top.setLayout(self.layout_top)
        #  нижняя часть
        self.frame_bottom = QFrame()
        self.layout_bottom = QVBoxLayout()
        self.bot_table = QTableWidget()
        self.bot_table.setRowCount(20)
        self.layout_bottom.addWidget(self.bot_table)
        self.frame_bottom.setLayout(self.layout_bottom)
        # Splitter
        self.splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter2.addWidget(self.frame_top)
        self.splitter2.addWidget(self.frame_bottom)
        self.layout_main_window.addWidget(self.splitter2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: спасибо, это работает и довольно легко в использовании. Но я столкнулся с новой проблемой. Если в главном окне не QTableWidget, а QWidget, на котором много элементов, то я не могу изменить размер этого виджета, т.к. движение останавливается, дойдя до элементов. Я создал новый вопрос для этой темы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1520093/pyqt5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-qsplitter-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-qwidget